# force specific struct in implementation of combination of traits

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to define two traits that can later be implemented in several ways.
First is trait `A` and second trait `B` which is basically a vector of elements that implement trait `A`.

```rust
trait A {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

trait B {
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
    fn add<T: A>(&mut self, item: T) -> bool;
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct ImplA {
    name: String,
}

impl A for ImplA {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }
}

struct ImplB {
    items: Vec<ImplA>,
}

impl B for ImplB {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.items.len()
    }

    fn add(&mut self, item: ImplA) -> bool {
        if !self.items.contains(&item) {
            self.items.push(item);
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

the code of the `add` function forces the item to implement type A.
Then I define two structs `ImplA` that implements trait `A` without problems
and then struct `ImplB` that should implement trait `B` but only accept items of
type `ImplA`.

I have tried several combinations for the signature of the `add` function, but it does not compile successfully.

The original error is

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:32:33
   |
31 |     fn add<T: A>(&mut self, item: T) -> bool {
   |            ----- this type parameter
32 |         if !self.items.contains(&item) {
   |                                 ^^^^^ expected struct `ImplA`, found type parameter `ImplA`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&ImplA` (struct `ImplA`)
              found reference `&T` (type parameter `T`)
```

Which I think I understand, but the solution mentioned does not solve my problem, because it will imply that `ImplB` can accept any struct that implements `A` and that's not what I want.

Comment: Do implementations of `B` contain collections of values of the same type, or different types that all implement `A`?

Comment: Stop shadowing names with type parameters. If you have a struct called `implA`, the last thing you want to do is also call your type parameter `implA`.

Comment: @Aplet123 this is not the real code, I tried to make a minimal example of the problem, sorry if it is harder to read.

Comment: @PeterHall each implementation of B will containt only one type of As

Comment: @horaciotellez Good, because that's I assumed in my answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

One of the problems you are running into is that the type argument for `add()` allows a different implementation of `A` each time it is called, but elsewhere you are relying on it always being the same type for a given implementation of `B`.

In Rust, this constraint can be expressed using an associated type on the `B` trait:

```
trait B {
    type Item: A;
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
    fn add(&mut self, item: Self::Item) -> bool;
}
```

Then, when you implement `B`, you give a fixed type for `A` for that implementation:

```
impl B for ImplB {
    type Item = ImplA;
    
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.items.len()
    }

    fn add(&mut self, item: ImplA) -> bool {
        if !self.items.contains(&item) {
            self.items.push(item);
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```